# Create Postgres database if it doesn't exist when running spring boot application

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using `PostgreSQL` and `spring-boot-2.0.1` and want my app to create the database if it doesn't exist.
I have the below options in my `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
```

with the above i'm getting error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "mydb" does not exist
```

any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: the generate-ddl configuration only acts on tables and not on DB; if the DB doesn't exist it won't be created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all Postgres installations come with a default database, technically it should be possible to connect to it at the very beginning (when the application starts) and then to call

[CREATE DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

This is something you could do programmatically before spring initializes, but after the properties are read, for example in [Environment Post Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html)

The so-early invocation is required because you probably want to take advantage of the properties read by spring boot on one hand, but by the time the spring boot beans will start to get the newly created database in the "operational" state.

So, technically its possible. However, I can't see a real use-case for this scenario.
If it's for tests, then you can perfectly use the default Postgres database, that was mentioned in the very beginning of the question.

If it's for production environment - usually DBAs won't allow that, because in order to be able to run that `CREATE DATABASE` statement, the user that connects to Postgres (spring boot application in this case) should have a very "strong" *createdb* priviledge, something that DBA won't really want to share.

Answer (score 5):

**Spring Boot**

Postgres does not support `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`
So you can try a similar way and it worked for me see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYeuw.png)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityJwtApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class);
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            logger.debug("Creating database if not exist...");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/", "postgres", "postgres");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'database_name'");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
            resultSet.next();
            int count = resultSet.getInt(1);

            if (count <= 0) {
                statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE database_name");
                logger.debug("Database created.");
            } else {
                logger.debug("Database already exist.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                    logger.debug("Closed Statement.");
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    logger.debug("Closed Connection.");
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database if it doesn't exist with `spring boot`. At least with MySQL, we do:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

So it should be the same with PostgreSQL:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

This doesn't work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this won't work for postgres. it only works with mysql

Comment: As mentioned, this solution doesn't work for Postgres.

Comment: Unfortunately, createDatabaseIfNotExist won't work for postgres.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

> It cannot be done like the way we do in `MySQL` you need to find a way
> to do it yourself out of `Spring Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to add the script for database creation ... even though, you don't have "if not exist" in postgres. Here is how i solved the issue with a docker file, but you can do a sql script in postgres i guess. I put this inside initdb.sh ...

```
set -e
export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD;
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "root" --dbname "mydb" <<-EOSQL
  SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE mydb' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb')\gexec
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO root;
  \connect mydb root
EOSQL
```