# How to auto create database and table when use TenantConnectionResolver to dynamic datasource?

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, multi-tenant, quarkus-hibernate-orm

In quarkus application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.110:5432/test
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update
quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE
```

And use `TenantResolver` to resolve tenantId

```java
@PersistenceUnitExtension
@RequestScoped
public class CustomTenantResolver implements TenantResolver {

  @Override
  public String getDefaultTenantId() {
    return TenantUtil.NONE.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String resolveTenantId() {
    return TenantUtil.getTenantId().toString();
  }
}
```

Then use `TenantConnectionResolver` to resolve dataSource

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@PersistenceUnitExtension
public class DataSourceTenantConnectionResolver implements TenantConnectionResolver {

  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url")
  String url;

  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
  String username;

  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
  String password;

  private final Map<String, ConnectionProvider> map = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public ConnectionProvider resolve(String tenantId) {
    System.out.println("resolve ConnectionProvider " + tenantId);
    if (map.containsKey(tenantId)) {
      return map.get(tenantId);
    }
    ConnectionProvider provider;
    if (tenantId.equals(TenantUtil.NONE)) {
      provider = new QuarkusConnectionProvider(createDataSource(url, "test", username, password));
    } else {
      provider =
          new QuarkusConnectionProvider(
              createDataSource(
                  "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.110:5432/tenant"
                      + tenantId
                      + "?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&characterEncoding=utf-8&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",
                  "tenant" + tenantId,
                  "root",
                  "root"));
    }
    map.put(tenantId, provider);
    return provider;
  }

  private AgroalDataSource createDataSource(
      String url, String database, String username, String password) {
    try {
      AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier configurationSupplier =
          new AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier();
      AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier connectionPoolConfig =
          configurationSupplier.connectionPoolConfiguration();
      connectionPoolConfig.maxSize(1000);

      AgroalConnectionFactoryConfigurationSupplier connectionFactoryConfig =
          connectionPoolConfig.connectionFactoryConfiguration();
      connectionFactoryConfig.jdbcUrl(url);
      connectionFactoryConfig.principal(new NamePrincipal(username));
      connectionFactoryConfig.credential(new SimplePassword(password));
      connectionFactoryConfig.initialSql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + database);

      return AgroalDataSource.from(configurationSupplier.get());
    } catch (SQLException | RuntimeException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Exception while creating datasource for " + url, e);
    }
  }
}
```

#### The question 1

Unable to automatically create a database through jdbcUrl of `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`. Is this the expected behavior? So i have use to `connectionFactoryConfig.initialSql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + database)`

#### The question 2

How to automatically create tables like `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to automatically create a database through jdbcUrl of createDatabaseIfNotExist=true. Is this the expected behavior? So i have use to connectionFactoryConfig.initialSql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + database)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669197/6692043

> How to automatically create tables like quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update ?

I'm not sure you can directly call Hibernate ORM to do that, at least not without a significant effort, since most of those tools are designed with single-tenancy in mind.

I'd recommend just [dumping Hibernate ORM's schema initialization scripts](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.scripts.generation), preferably while you develop the application, and manually applying those whenever you connect to a new datasource (and you detect it's empty).

Ideally, you'd use Flyway for such things. But given you're using dynamic datasources, you probably can't rely on [Quarkus' `Flyway` object injection](https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway#using-the-flyway-object) and will have to build the `Flyway` object manually.